# How to set proctitle to ascii in auditd?

Tags: rsyslog, audit, auditd

I configured auditd to send the logs to SIEM through rsyslog.
But when I get those logs the proctitle is in hex.

Ex.:

```
<134>Aug 25 17:08:44 vmauditd tag_audit_log: node=vmauditd type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1692983317.146:7444): proctitle=6E63002D6C766E700032323232
```

I would like it to come like this:

```
<134>Aug 25 17:08:44 vmauditd tag_audit_log: node=vmauditd type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1692983317.146:7444): proctitle=nc -lvnp 2222
```

How do I configure audit so that this is possible?

I read here:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-understanding_audit_log_files that ..."*The field is encoded in hexadecimal notation to not allow the user to influence the Audit log parser.*"

I've seen in some places some people putting the proctitle in ascii, but I'm not 100% sure if it was an output of `ausearch -i`.